# [PL/SQL]EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CREATE INDEX is failing with invalid CREATE INDEX option

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, plsql, execute-immediate

For every *table_name* I need to create index based on *index_required* returned from specified query
I wrote below PL/SQL Procedure:

```
DECLARE
  sIndexRequired  VARCHAR(50);
  sTableName      VARCHAR(50);
  cSQL             CLOB ;
BEGIN

  FOR r IN [...] --I'm getting index_required and table_name from here
    
  LOOP
    
        sIndexRequired := r.index_required;
        sTableName     := r.table_name;
        
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX ' || sTableName || 
        CASE WHEN sIndexRequired = 'XXX'  THEN '_YYY' 
             [...] -- more case when cases
        END
        || ' ON ' || sTableName || ' (' || sIndexRequired || ') TABLESPACE xyz;';
        
  END LOOP;
  END;
/
```

But it's failing with

```
Error report -
ORA-02158: invalid CREATE INDEX option
ORA-06512: at line 46
ORA-06512: at line 46
02158. 00000 -  "invalid CREATE INDEX option"
*Cause:    An option other than COMPRESS, NOCOMPRESS, PCTFREE, INITRANS,
           MAXTRANS, STORAGE, TABLESPACE, PARALLEL, NOPARALLEL, RECOVERABLE,
           UNRECOVERABLE, LOGGING, NOLOGGING, LOCAL, or GLOBAL was specified.
*Action:   Choose one of the valid CREATE INDEX options.
```

Can anyone has idea how can I get this work?

Thanks,
Michał

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you're **blind** and have **no idea** what you are doing.

Instead of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`,

- declare local `VARCHAR2` variable large enough to contain the whole `CREATE INDEX` statement
- compose the statement and put it into the variable
- **display** its contents on the screen (use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`)
- copy/paste it and execute it

  - if it is not clear what's wrong at the first sight, Oracle will now tell you what went wrong. If you use SQL*Plus, an asterisk `*` will point exactly to the failing spot
- fix the error
- run the procedure again

Once you're sure that you did it right, remove *print to screen* and use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

---

As commented, it turns out that it was the trailing semi-colon within `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` that caused problems.

```
No : || ') TABLESPACE xyz;';
Yes: || ') TABLESPACE xyz';
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing for first place and I'm getting correct, working "CREATE INDEX" are created eg "CREATE INDEX index_name_xxx ON table_name (index_required) TABLESPACE _xyz;" So you'll answer won't help

Comment: Unfortunately, Oracle disagrees with you. If you did it correctly, it would have **created** the index, not return an error.

Comment: Ah, yes - remove the semi-colon, here: ... TABLESPACE xyz;'; the one right behind `xyz;`. Then run your code again.

Comment: Commands in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE must NOT end with a semi-colon.

Comment: Isn't that nice?